# Can I use vtkCellLocator to find intersected cells by line

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, mesh, vtk, raytracing

I have mesh grid and there is a line passing through several cells. I want to get all the cells which are intersected by line.
I have start and end points of line and I have mesh vertexes coordinates.
What is the fastest way to compute this condition, is there any way, I could use vtk class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the vtk class `vtkOBBTree`, and the method `IntersectWithLine`. This is python, but you get the idea of how it works [here](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/0403e024d2fcd0592a141f266c75a6415dc016fa/vedo/mesh.py#L1535)

```py
from vedo import dataurl, Mesh, Line, show
m = Mesh(dataurl+'bunny.obj')
l = Line([-0.15,0.1,0], [0.1,0.1,0], c='k', lw=3)
pts_cellids = m.intersectWithLine(l, returnIds=True)
print(pts_cellids)
show(m, l, axes=1)
```

[image]

You should get cells ids: [3245 1364]